# Free jqGrid 4.9.0 - How to get the original value of an inline editing for the row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm currently trying to do an inline editing for a given row in the grid.  Since the double click opens all the columns that are "editable" on a given row, the "save" operation is sending back to the server the entire values to be updated, not just those who got actually changed.

In order not to send the server redundant updates, I would like to "compare" the values before the update and after.  So that I can only send the server the columns who actually got changed.

What is the best way to achieve that, and how do I get the original row values in order to make the comparison.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I find the question interesting. I post below an example of the implementation of your requirements. I didn't wrote the problem in the common case to make the code a little shorter. I suggest you to define `serializeSaveData` callback used by inline editing. You can specify it inside of `inlineEditing` parameter of the grid for example (see [the documentation](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods)):

```
inlineEditing: {
    serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
        var data = $.extend({}, postData), // make copy of input data
            p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
            savedRow = p.savedRow, iColByName = p.iColByName, colModel = p.colModel,
            i, l = savedRow.length, prop, oldData, cm, iCol, v;
        for (i = 0; i < l ; i++) {
            // below we suppose that idname of postData is deafult - id
            // to make the code more simple.
            // One can use p.prmNames.oper or p.keyName in more common case
            if (savedRow[i].id === postData.id) {
                oldData = savedRow[i];
                for (prop in oldData) {
                    if (oldData.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        iCol = iColByName[prop];
                        if (iCol !== undefined && colModel[iCol] != null) {
                            cm = colModel[iCol];
                            v = oldData[prop];
                            if (cm.formatter === "date" && (cm.formatoptions || {}).sendFormatted !== true) {
                                v = $.unformat.date.call(this, v, cm);
                            }
                            if (v === data[prop]) {
                                delete data[prop];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return data; // object with oper, id and modified propertied
    }
}
```

The above code examine the data which will be send to the server after editing and remove all properties which are not modified. The server code should of cause don't interpret the data as `NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks, I need to learn it as I see you added some cool new options.

Comment: When is the serializeSaveData get called?  It seems I can't get it to be executed.  Trying to alert(1) from it, also don't do much.  formEditing: {
     savekey: [true, 13],
     closeOnEscape: true,
     closeAfterEdit: true,
     closeAfterEdit: true
    },
    actionsNavOptions: { editformbutton: true },
    inlineEditing: { keys: true, serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
     alert(1);

Comment: @Tal: `serializeSaveData` will be called before making Ajax request to save the data to the server. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L290-L293) or [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L290-L293).

Comment: Might be it's not being called since I have used the call back save function for my implemenration.  In that case, seems like I might just grab the row original during onRowSelect, and iterate over it from within the implemention I have in the call back.

Comment: @Tal: You should post your code if you want that I help you to find the problem. I tested the code which I posted on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/inlineEdit.htm). It uses HTTP GET instead of POST for saving the edited data, but one can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to see what will be appended to the URL during saving. One sees only the properties of changed fileds.